# python abstract method with more specific arguments

Tags: python, types, interface, mypy, abstract-methods

I am getting a type warning when implementing an `abstractmethod` in a more explicit way, why is that wrong?

I have the following interface

```py
from typing import Any
from abc import abstractmethod, ABCMeta

class SaveDataInterface(metaclass=ABCMeta):
    @abstractmethod
    def save_data(self, data: Any, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
```

When implementing the following `FileSaver` class, mypy throws an error
`error: Signature of "save_data" incompatible with supertype "SaveDataInterface"`

```py
class FileSaver(SaveDataInterface):
    def save_data(self, data: str, file_path: str, *args, **kwargs):
        with open(file_path, 'w') as file:
            file.write(data)
```

---

It doesn't seem to me that `FileSaver.save_data` somehow breaks the `abstractmethod` `save_data` functionality, Is there another way to implement a more explicit function signature?

Comment: If a type S is a subtype of type T, then you want to be able to replace T everywhere with S without altering behavior (i.e. Liskov Substitution Principle). In your case, because parent-class SaveDataInterface takes *more general argument types* you can't use the child class, which takes *less generaly* argument types. So, overriden methods must be contra (or co) variant in there *argument types*, but not in their *return types*. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_(computer_science)#Inheritance_in_object-oriented_languages

Comment: So, in Python, you are free to do this, but it isn't type-safe, and mypy correctly complains